# Disable Highlighting of Strings in Visual Studio

Tags: string, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting, highlight

All of my strings in visual studio are highlighted (see screenshot)[image]

This makes it very difficult when i'm actually highlighting something or using the find functionality.

I cannot find an option for this anywhere, anyone know how to disable this?

This is Visual Studio Community 2017

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools` > `Options` > `Fonts and Colors`. On the `Display Items`, find `String` and change the `Item background` color to whatever the color of your editor background is.
[image]